# Change a certain field of the document-set based of creation of a certain document type with workflows

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-enterprise, workflow, document-set

In my document-set two different document types are allowed; let’s say document type A and document type B.

Is it possible to change the field X in my document-set when document of type A is created inside the document set and change the field Y in my document-set when document of type B  is created inside the document?

I want to have a field (column) of type YES/NO in my document-set which is called “A is available” and the other field (column) is called “B is available”. By default they are set to NO but when the document of type “A” is created inside the document set “A is available” is set to “YES” and when document of type “B” is created inside the document set “B is available” is set to “YES”.

Answer (score 0):

So what i understand from your query is you can use the simple SharePoint designer workflows to set the the column value according to your Document type.

http://office.microsoft.com/en-in/sharepoint-server-help/introduction-to-document-sets-HA101782466.aspx

http://sergeluca.wordpress.com/2011/06/05/sharepoint-2010-workflows-and-document-setsstart-the-workflow-when-a-new-item-is-createdbe-careful/

Comment: Thanks for the reply but I think my case is a bit different from the what you understood! how can I say this with workflows: 1-when a new document of type A is created set the column "A is available" in the corresponding document set (document set that can contanin document of type A and B) 2- when a new document of type B is created, set the column "B is available" in the corresponding document set? The problem is, when I create a workflow for a document of type A, I don't know how to access the fields of the document set...

Comment: Can you create two content types and associate your document sets with it. How do you distinguish between document A and document B?

Comment: in document-sets you can say what are the allowed document types as in this image: http://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/getfile/481039   referring to this image, document A is of type "Image" and document B is of type "Audio".

Comment: You can add check for content type in your workflow

Comment: there are 5 checks in workflow actions: 1-Check In Item 2-Checklist item permission levels 3-check list item permissions 4-check out item 5-discard check out item. do you mean using one of these actions on my document set? could you tell me what you mean by "adding check for content type" more precisely?

Comment: What type of workflowa are you using? Sharepoint designer ?

Comment: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/workflows_for_product_catalogs/archive/2012/11/02/create-a-simple-workflow-that-reads-from-and-writes-to-a-product-catalog.aspx